# why reactive forms prod build giving error?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Trying to build an angular application using below command

```
ng build --prod
```

Getting following error.

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory.
```

Application Details:

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.0
Node: 8.2.1
typescript: 2.3.4
webpack: 3.10.0
OS: win32 x64
```

How to figure out these type of errors in source code? Because i am getting this error after creating some components which uses reactive forms.

Help me on this.

Comment: I found similar kind of issue is already placed on official angular repo. Please check https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9157.

Comment: would not be surprised if it has something to do with the `aot`. can you try ng serve with `--aot`

Comment: Why is the reason to not use the angular-cli lastest? (NOTE: Be sure you're importing ReactiveFormsModule in your app.module.ts)

Comment: Its one year old app. We can't modify suddenly to the latest. Yes we are importing ReactiveFormsModule.

Comment: @Stavm ng serve --aot works fine. But not ng build --prod.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem have relation with reactive forms. but there is an open issue in [github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5618) about it you can check that but as a temporary work around you can allocate memory for node using this command and build your projet

```
node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod
```

Comment: Build is success after removing the components which is using reactive forms.

Comment: I'm not certain about it but removing the components might have solved the problem whether it was using reactive forms or not. The error occurs as the size of the project gets bigger

Comment: node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod.    
 Build got success.

Comment: App main.bundle.js size is 4.06 MB. Is my app is too big?

Comment: am not sure  my app main.bundle.js size is 2.8 MB but it run in to the same error and this is how i'm fixing it till i find a permanent solution to it